# Inserting Label Before the Select List

Tags: jquery, html, css

I am using jQuery Mobile to create a page using the following code:

```
<fieldset data-role="controlgroup" data-type="horizontal">
    <legend>Width:</legend>
    <label>This never gets displayed on the screen</label>
    <select name="select-native-11" id="select-native-11">
        <option value="#">2</option>
        <option value="#">3</option>
        <option value="#">4</option>
    </select>
    <label for="select-native-12">Select Inches</label>
    <select name="select-native-12" id="select-native-12">
        <option value="#">1/2</option>
        <option value="#">1/3</option>
        <option value="#">1/4</option>
    </select>
</fieldset>
</form>
```

I get the following result:

[image]

How can I have the "Width" text and the select elements in a single line?

Comment: can you create a fiddle please?

Comment: Just a guess without seeing css. Try setting the CSS for `legend` as `display:inline-block;float:left;`.

Comment: Fiddle does not have jQuery Mobile Library!

Comment: @johndoe, you can add external links to fiddle.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I am not sure what styles you inherit from jQuery mobile.. But basically you would want something like this.

```
legend {
    display:inline-block;
    float:left;
}
```

**Demo:**

http://jsfiddle.net/eLjqf6Lm/